# Refactoring code inside a Ruby Proc in a rails_admin custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, ruby-2.1

A little background:

My app has `tools` which have `permission_levels`. There are `User`'s that have authorization for some `tools` and not others. The admin panel is built using the [rails_admin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin).

If the admin is editing a `User` and that `User` has access to `tools` that the admin does not, these tools do not show up in the edit view (this is desired). However, when the admin updates the `User`, the `User` loses the associations to `tools` and `permission_levels` that were not shown.

To combat that, I overrode the `#edit` action inside RailsAdmin. The resulting code is a bit of a mess, and I'd like to refactor by pulling out related code into methods, but the section is wrapped inside a `Proc`.

How can I pull out the code below into methods? Specifically, the `register_instance_option :controller` section.

```
.
.
.
module Actions
  class Edit < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base

    register_instance_option :member? do
      true
    end

    register_instance_option :route_fragment do
      'edit'
    end

    register_instance_option :http_methods do
      [:get, :put]
    end

    register_instance_option :visible? do
      authorized?
    end

    register_instance_option :controller do
      Proc.new do
        if @object.class.base_class.name == 'User'
          if request.get?
            session[:tools] = (@object.tools - Tool.admined_by(current_user)).map(&:id)
            pl = session[:tools].map do |t|
              tl = Tool.find(t)
              tl.permission_levels
            end
            session[:permission_levels] = []
            pl.flatten.each do |p|
              session[:permission_levels] << p if @object.permission_levels.include?(p)
            end
            session[:permission_levels].map!(&:id)
          elsif request.put?
            duped_tools = session[:tools].dup
            params[:user][:tool_ids] = duped_tools.
              concat(params[:user][:tool_ids]).uniq!.delete_if { |id| id == "" }.
              map { |id| id.to_i }
            duped_permission_levels = session[:permission_levels].dup
            params[:user][:permission_level_ids] = duped_permission_levels.
              concat(params[:user][:permission_level_ids]).uniq!.delete_if { |id| id == "" }.
              map { |id| id.to_i }
            if @object.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit!)
              session[:tools] = nil
              session[:permission_levels] = nil
              duped_session = nil
              flash[:success] = t("admin.flash.successful", :name => @model_config.label, :action => t("admin.actions.edit.done"))
              redirect_to index_path
            else
              flash[:error] = t("admin.flash.error", :name => @model_config.label, :action => t("admin.actions.edit.done"))
              redirect_path = back_or_index
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end

    register_instance_option :link_icon do
      'icon-pencil'
    end
  end
end
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is several code improvements in order to **use less lines** and possibly **better performances**:

## Use less lines:

```
# All `register_instance_option` can be refactored in a one-line bock:
register_instance_option :member? do
  true
end
# to
register_instance_option(:member?) { true }
```

## Better use of Rails' methods:

```
if @object.class.base_class.name == 'User'
# can be changed to:
if @object.kind_of?(User) # will not work if @object is a Admin which inherits from User class

array_of_ids.delete_if { |id| id == "" }
# can be changed to:
array_of_ids.select(&:present?)

array = session[:tools].map do
  # your logic
end
array = array.flatten
# can be changed to:
array = session[:tools].flat_map do
  # your logic
end
# no need for a flatten (thanks to `.flat_map`)

session[:tools] = nil
session[:permission_levels] = nil
duped_session = nil
# can be changed to:
session[:tools] = session[:permission_levels] = duped_session = nil
```

---

I would have refactored your code into this: (feel free to comment this)

```
if @object.kind_of?(User)
  if request.get?
    session[:tools] = @object.tools.where('id NOT IN (?)', Tool.admined_by(current_user).pluck(:id)) # better performances
    session[:tools] = session[:tools].includes(:permission_levels).flat_map(&:permission_levels)
    session[:permission_levels] = []
    session[:tools].each do |p|
      session[:permission_levels] << p.id if @object.permission_levels.include?(p)
    end

  elsif request.put?
    duped_tools = session[:tools].dup
    params[:user][:tool_ids] = duped_tools.concat(params[:user][:tool_ids]).uniq.select(&:present?).map(&:to_i)
    duped_permission_levels = session[:permission_levels].dup
    params[:user][:permission_level_ids] = duped_permission_levels.concat(params[:user][:permission_level_ids]).uniq.select(&:present?).map(&:to_i)
    if @object.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit!)
      session[:tools] = session[:permission_levels] = nil
      flash[:success] = t("admin.flash.successful", name: @model_config.label, name: t("admin.actions.edit.done"))
      redirect_to index_path
    else
      flash[:error] = t("admin.flash.error", name: @model_config.label, action: t("admin.actions.edit.done"))
      redirect_path = back_or_index
    end
  end
end
```